# Is there a name for sum of successive sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I had some fun playing with $\sum$ and found this sequence.

$a_{n1} = 1+1+1+...+1 = n$

$a_{n2} = 1+2+3+... = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{k1} = \sum_{k=1}^nk = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$a_{n3} = 1+3+6+... = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{k2}= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k(k+1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$
(Note that it's not a sum of $k^2$, $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$)

...

$a_{nm} = \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m-1)}{(m)!}$

(I don't know how I should name the $nm$-th term)

As you can see for each sequence you sum the previous sum from 1 to n.

Is there any name for this particular sequence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), in particular the [diagonals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Diagonals) !

Comment: So it's a sum of Pascal's triangle, adding all diagonals starting in n-th position from 1 to m! Thank you.  Are there any names for this kind of sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension of the product in the numerator down to 1 gives
$$
a_{n,m} = \frac{1\cdot 2\cdot (n-1) }{1\cdot 2\cdots (n-1)}\times \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+m-1)}{m!}
= \frac{(n+m-1)!}{m!(n-1)!} = \binom{n+m-1}{m}.
$$
So that iteration of partial sums gives binomial coefficients. The fact that the partial sums for $a_{n,m}$ lead to $a_{n,m+1}$ is given in the aforementioned wikipedia section of pascal triangle diagonals.